# How to make a POST request with Data and Headers in Python

Tags: php, python, html, ajax

I'm trying to get the full HTML content of this page: http://www.ims.com.br/ims/visite/programacao/2017/03/05

But, a part of the HTML code came from an AJAX request on: http://www.ims.com.br/ajax/programacao.php ¹

This requests, according, the Web Inspector of Chrome had the following Headers:

```
POST /ajax/programacao.php HTTP/1.1
Host: www.ims.com.br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 51
Accept: text/html, */*; q=0.01
Origin: http://www.ims.com.br
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://www.ims.com.br/ims/visite/programacao/2017/03/05
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: PHPSESSID=k3cu5ho6ev7g9j56jpoosqth94; _ga=GA1.3.252384583.1488689974
```

And the following Form Data:

```
date=1488682800&visualizacao=hoje&onde=&oque=&como=
```

where Date is the timestamp.

But when I do the request.post in Python with the following code, the HTML coming from the page ¹ isn't completed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8
# Instituto Moreira Salles

import os
import re
import time
import requests

def main():

    numday = time.strftime("%w")

    if(numday == '1'):
        timestamp = str(int(time.time()) - 86400)
    else:
        timestamp = str(int(time.time()))

    payload = {'date': timestamp, 'visualizacao': 'hoje', 'onde' : '', 'oque' : '', 'como' : ''}

    header = {'accept': 'text/html, */*; q=0.01',
            'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
            'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
            'connection': 'keep-alive',
            'content-length': '51',
            'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'cookie': 'PHPSESSID=k3cu5ho6ev7g9j56jpoosqth94; _gat=1; _ga=GA1.3.252384583.1488689974; PHPSESSID=2jmgciitgoub7o74up18rqikl6',
            'origin': 'http://www.ims.com.br',
            'referer': 'http://www.ims.com.br/ims/visite/programacao/2017/03/05',
            'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36',
            'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'}

    hhtml = requests.post('http://www.ims.com.br/ajax/programacao.php', data=payload), headers=header)

    print hhtml.content

main()
```

But if I do the same request in the Chrome Extension App "Advanced REST Client" the HTML content is completed.

Anyone know how to do a right request POST with Headers and Data in Python?

Comment: PHPSESSID is probably messing it up for you. It's passed as a cookie. Your python code is actually sending two of them, but that's probably not as big of a problem as the fact that you're likely sending in invalid SessionID.

Comment: I agree with pbuck: you can probably solve this by getting the initial page first with python requests, and extracting the PHPSESSID from the request headers, then making the POST request you wish to do.  You also seem to have the headers part commented out in your code, which I assume is just an oversight here.